# How to send Hindi characters in URL parameters from front-end and store it in MySQL using PHP?

Tags: php, angular, frontend

I have designed a form in Angular 4 which takes Hindi as input characters. Using HTTP GET method, I am sending the data to the back-end (written in PHP) so as to store it in MySQL(tables already in UTF8 charset). 
The problem I am facing is that I am unable to store the data in it's original format, which is Hindi, instead some garbage value is getting stores.

Comment: There is not enough information to answer this question. Does the AJAX send the characters encoded? Does PHP get them correctly? Does the DB connection send them to MySQL correct? Is the DB set to store utf8 chars? Are the characters stored correctly and the issue is retrieving? Please narrow down the issue.

Comment: DB is setup to store utf8 characters. The characters are not getting stored correctly. PHP retrieves the data as sent (using HTTPCLIENT). Sample of sent request: http://abcd.com/save/addMember.php?name=%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%B0&company=%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%B0&city=%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%B0&contact=1234567898

Comment: What does `print_r($_GET)` show, characters as expected? Your DB link has the charset?

Comment: It shows the characters that I am sending from front-end. Also, I have already set the DB's collation to utf8_general_ci. Do we have to set it explicitly before executing the query in PHP?

Comment: Yes, your DB connection needs to be set to UTF8 for it to send it as UTF8.

Comment: Alrighty, let me try...

Comment: I did mysqli_set_charset($connectionObject, 'utf8') before executing the query. It's working. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Great, good luck going forward. In the future please try to provide more information when posting.

Comment: Sure. I'll keep it in mind before posting. :)